# i used my hp 840 g7 docking station charger by accident for less than half hour. will this damage my laptop

Tags: charger

i accidentally used docking station charger for my hp laptop (840 g7) for less than half hour. I don't know how much more power the docking station charger has but will this damage my system?

Comment: What makes you think this would damage your system?

Comment: i used the charger that plugs into docking station separately.It obviously has more voltage than the laptop charger

Answer (score 1):

## It's completely safe.

Electricity has *voltage* measured in volts `V` and *current* measured in amperes `A`.

The voltage of a power supply must match what the device expects with ±5% tolerance (sometimes more). The docking station certainly uses the same voltage as the laptop, so you're good here.

The current works a bit differently. It's not "pushed" into devices, but "pulled" from the power adapter. The adapter won't "push" all the current it's capable of providing if the device is not willing to consume it. The device will use as much power as it wants and the adapter will be working at a fraction of its max current.